# How to add files to raspberry pi from web

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-2, software-recommendation

I want to create an web interface to my raspberry pi. I want to control files that is in raspberry. I want to upload files to it, delete it and etc. (Want to do all this from web interface). How to do it? Any recommendations?

Is it possible to do with python? Need any examples, thank you guys!

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is irrelevant to your question as any Linux box can be used.

Comment: @joan Raspberry Pi is relevant since not all software can run on it.

Answer (score 1):

Trying out OwnCloud is not a bad suggestion (note it's written in PHP, not Python, if that makes any difference), but I'd advise against manually installing it from a tarball. You'll absolutely want security updates for server software facing the Internet. You can install it from OpenSUSE repositories as described [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/owncloud-install-debian-8-jessie/):

```sh
echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/community/Debian_8.0/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list
wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:ownCloud:community/Debian_8.0/Release.key
# Might be a good idea to check the key manually at this point.
apt-key add - < Release.key
apt-get update
apt-get install owncloud
```